# Graph with auto layout using d3 (a tree with multiple parent nodes)

Tags: graph, d3.js, tree

How to draw a graph with auto layout, many-to-many with lines not crossing the boxes using d3?

I'd like to accomplish something like this: 
http://www.graphdracula.net/showcase/
http://live.yworks.com/yfiles-for-html/1.1/demos/DataBinding/demo.yfiles.binding.interactivegraphsource/index.html

I guess that's the best description of what I need (something like tree, but with multiple parents):
[image]

Comment: D3 doesn't implement a layout for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dagre-d3 is the best solution that I found:

https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3

Comment: This library is deprecated. Is there any replacement?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who comes across this, here's another possible solution: (see the "Directed Graph with downward-pointing edges" example)

http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/

It can also be plugged into d3.js and used in place of the force layout.

Comment: Agreed, but be aware of [WebCola Missing documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889372/webcola-missing-documentation)

Answer (score 2):

To minimize line crossings, you probably need a layered digraph layout.  Just google that phrase.

Comment: As stated above, Dagre-d3 is the best solutions

Comment: @ElKopyto This library is deprecated. Is there any replacement?